# What properties are required for a safety window on a 10w laser enclosure?

Tags: materials, safety, lasers

What properties are required for a safety window on a laser engraver enclosure with a 10w diode based cutting head?

405nm wavelength

Comment: If you cannot figure out the basic principles from Googling, then I suggest you not have a direct window at all at that power level. Use a camera behind a safety window instead. Needless to say, only use certified safety window material. Since you're asking on here I am assuming you do not understand what you found since I found this very quickly: https://d3qi0qp55mx5f5.cloudfront.net/researchsafety/docs/Laser_Safety_Calculations.pdf?mtime=1610127144

Comment: Most developed countries have a standards association which publishes standards in relation to safety. Check with the standards association in your country.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I'm wondering why you didn't simply take the formula on that document and complete them for a 10w laser with a 405nm wavelength and post them in the form of an answer. Should be easy for someone who understands the document, right?

Comment: @AaarghZombies Taktes time and I never claimed to understand. There are some parameters at the very top which I haven't worked with and also were not provided. Furthermore, that's doing all your work for you and it's not wise for you to not understand it when its your eyes that are at stake. You should take the time to try to understand them and if you don't, then don't risk your eyes and go with a camera. Brief vague questions either mean the person completely did not understand what they found or that they never bothered searching in the first place, but it tends to be the latter.

Comment: @DKNguyen, If you don't know the answer, please don't comment. This is not a chat forum.

Comment: Questions with zero research shouldn't get real answers either.

Comment: This is not a chat forum, save this for Reddit.